# python not able to share variable across files

Tags: python, global-variables

So I have read that the way to share globals across files is to create a module which holds globals and import this in all python files needing to access the global. However it doesn't seem to work as expected for me (Python 3.6+)

Simple directory structure:

```
run.py
mypack/
   -- globals.py
   -- stuff.py
   -- __init__.py
```

I have a global var in globals.py which I need to modify in main file (run.py) and finally print out while exiting the program. It does not seem to work:

__init__.py:

```
from .stuff import *
```

globals.py:

```
test = 'FAIL'
```

stuff.py:

```
import atexit
from .globals import test

def cya():
    print ("EXIT: test = " + test)

atexit.register(cya)

def hi():
    print('HI')
```

run.py:

```
import mypack
import mypack.globals as globals

mypack.hi()
globals.test = 'PASS'

print ("MAIN: test = " + globals.test)
```

Output on script execution:

```
HI
MAIN: test = PASS
EXIT: test = FAIL
```

Clearly the exit routine (cya) did not show the correct value of global value that was modified in run.py. Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: A side note - don't use `globals` as module name/allias. It's [built-in functiom](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals)

Comment: @buran thanks - so I changed `globals` to `universal` for my usage. In any case it does not change the question.

Comment: if you import globls multiple times, variable is reinitialized at each import. You should create Singleton object.

Comment: @PeterTrcka great - that was the issue

Comment: @PeterTrcka absolutely incorrect

Answer (score 0):

the python documentation might help you on this one.

https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules

Comment: that is what I got the idea of using a module to store globals. However when implementing it, it doesnt work as expected.

Comment: try `stuff.test = "whatever"`?

Comment: `mypack.stuff.test = 'whatever'` works but it defeats the purpose. The aim is not to modify module local variables. It is to only modify the variables in globals module and have that reflect throughout.

Comment: I guess I dont understand your question then? It looks like you are trying to modify the data of the variable in a different file.

Comment: my real use case is to pass the logger and log_count variables across modules (which would not be strings, but other objects). But I just framed a simpler question here to explain the issue.
I will have likely several modules created. Each one will need to access the global and potentially modify it. Having each module access the local variable from every other module is not feasible. I want to import a set of globals, and ensure that modification to them is reflected in every other module immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was: at each import all variables will be reinitialized thier values. Use singleton object:

**universal.py**

```py
import logging


class GlobVars:

    _instances = {}
    
    def __new__(cls, logger, counter_start=0):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            print("Creating Instance")
            cls._instances[cls] = super(GlobVars, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls._instances[cls]

    def __init__(self, logger, counter_start=0):
        self.logger = logger
        self.counter = counter_start

glob_vars = GlobVars(logger=logging.getLogger("basic_logger"))
```

**run.py**

```py
from universal import glob_vars

glob_vars.logger.info("One logger rulles them all")
```

Comment: This is **completely wrong**

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga can you explain why this is wrong. adding it to a class worked for me.

Comment: Can you be more specific? This type of comments don't help.

Comment: Your claim that a module is re-initialized. Totally wrong. And easily verifiable as wrong.

Comment: Not module, but variables from this module. I think I understand your concern. You meant that module is imported only once during whole program?

Comment: As an aside, your `GlobVars` class is not a singleton.... not sure what the point of overriding `__new__` was here...

Comment: @PeterTrcka **totally wrong**. They absolutely do not get re-initialized. And yes, modules are cached once they are imported. The problem with the OP is that they used `from .globals import test`, this creates a *new global variable* in the module doing that. Assignments to `global.test` won't affect *that variable*. See the linked duplicate

Comment: A module already is a singleton object, you just have to *use that object*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga you are right. That definition was not Singleton. So you meant that there is no need to implement singleton pattern just using the object will work ?

Comment: @PeterTrcka just using *the module object yes*. In general, the singleton pattern is never really useful. certainly not in Python. In this case, the simples solution is to change `from .globals import test` to `import .globals` and then use `globals.test`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for explanation. I have never thought about it this way: if modules are cached, and you import object, you are still using the same object, and if any other module change attribute value, this change will be reflected every where, because it is still that one object. Am I correct?

Comment: @PeterTrcka yep, that is correct

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236984/discussion-between-peter-trcka-and-juanpa-arrivillaga).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @PeterTrcka for pointing out the issue. Also thanks to @buran for indicating globals is a bad name for module since its inbuilt function. Here is the working solution:

directory structure:

```
run.py
mypack/
   -- universal.py
   -- stuff.py
   -- __init__.py
```

__init__.py:

```
from .stuff import *
```

universal.py:

```
class GlobalVars:
  test = 'FAIL'
```

stuff.py:

```
import atexit
from .universal import GlobalVars

def cya():
    print ("EXIT: test = " + GlobalVars.test)

atexit.register(cya)

def hi():
    print('HI')
```

run.py:

```
import mypack
from mypack.universal import GlobalVars

mypack.hi()
GlobalVars.test = 'PASS'

print ("MAIN: test = " + GlobalVars.test)
```

Output on script execution:

```
HI
MAIN: test = PASS
EXIT: test = PASS
```

Comment: That wasn't the actual issue, modules don't get re-initialized upon each import.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga then how come above solution works, but original question fails?

Comment: The problem is that you are importing like this: `from .globals import test`. This creates a *new* variable in the current module. Use `import globals` and then in `cya` use `globals.test`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks for correct solution. I didnt realize this creates a new local variable. So there is really no short way to access a global variable I guess.

Comment: It doesn't create a local variable, it *creates a global variable*. Global variables are really just "module level" in Python. This is a *good thing*